# How can i tell word to abbreviate "Figure" as "Fig."?

Tags: ms-word, figure, capitalization

i want to use automatic numeration of Figures by word. When i insert a caption, I can choose what kind of caption this is, and since i have a different language than english, i made a new Type "Figure". The problem is with referencing: When i insert a cross reference onto that figure, it inserts it as "Figure" and makes it bold, since i embolden the "Figure" part of the caption, to make it more visible.

How can i change this in the text to be abbreviated with "fig."? Its annoying that the capitalisation is wrong and that the whole word "Figure" is inserted, instead of just the abbreviation. How can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Word 2007 you can in the "Insert Caption" dialog check whether to include or exclude the label from the caption. So inserting a reference will make you show only the number, without "Figure" word, so you can type "Fig." manually.

[image]

(Picture taken from http://word.tips.net/T000890_Adding_Captions.html)

As far as I know it is not possible (this way) until Office 2007.